# Mocking login for remote services - Cucumber, Capybara, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara, webmock

I have a Rails application that has changed from user authentication via devise to accessing a remote API for authentication. For the test suite, this requires that I mock the https request for authentication and return a valid response.  We are using Cucumber and Capybara for testing and I am attempting to use the webmock Gem to mock the login response.

The login is initiated by a button click on a form (Capybara action 'click_button').

Unfortunately,  although webmock appears to be installed correctly (I am able to make a Net::HTTP POST request and this is recognized by Webmock), the POST to the remote authorization facility is not being captured by webmock.  I know that the form POST is making its way to the controller, because the stacktrace shows that the POST is being executed in the controller  as it should and the error message is "Errno::ECONNREFUSED at ... Failed to open TCP connection".

I have tried:

```
WebMock.stub_request(:any, '127.0.0.1').to_return(body: {STATUSCODE: 1}.to_json)
```

and

```
WebMock::stub_request(:any, '127.0.0.1').to_return(body: {STATUSCODE: 1}.to_json)
```

and

```
stub_request(:any, '127.0.0.1').to_return(body: {STATUSCODE: 1}.to_json)
```

I have tried putting the stub_request call in the devise_steps.rb file, just before the "click_button" command, as well as in the features/support/env.rb and features/support/webmock.rb file.

I assume that what I am doing is so common that it has to be possible, but I have found nothing that indicates why the stub_request is not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem was that the path on the stub_request was not complete. I had misread the webmock documentation....

Answer (score 0):

So the domain of the remote API for authentication is localhost? So it would be running on the same server with a different port? Then you have to mock the address with the port.

For instance your Rails app is running on port 80 and your auth API is running on 8080 then you have to do this.

```
stub_request(:any, '127.0.0.1:8080').to_return(body: {STATUSCODE: 1}.to_json)
```

I think Webmock should support different ports but I'm not 100% sure. Also have you set `WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)`?

https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#external-requests-can-be-disabled-while-allowing-localhost

### Edit:

If this is not working, I suggest you make the API URL configurable and e.g. set it in tests to `auth-api.com` and then mock this.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions.  The remote authentication is actually a domain, but for purposes of mocking, it really shouldn't matter.  I started out using the domain name, but fell back to localhost simply because I wanted to remove complexity. I experimented with adding the port number, but it made no difference in the behavior. As well, webmock on a Net::HTTP request worked for localhost without a port.

Comment: Well, there must be a difference between the test with Net::HTTP and you authentication. If I would guess, I would say it's because your Capybara tests already run a Rails server on localhost.